# Phil Sturgeon Codeigniter Rest Client results

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest, curl

So I am trying to use [Phil Sturgeon's rest codeigniter client](https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restclient) To interface with [Lob's Printing API](http://www.lob.com). But all I am getting with what I have set up in my controller is a blank result. I've tried using Twitters API with the same blank results.

If I do `var_dump($result);` where `$result` is the api call such as: `$result = $this->rest->get('addresses');` All I get is: `bool(false)` With both API's. My controller is set up like such:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Mailing extends CI_Controller {

   public function __construct()
   {
       parent::__construct();

       $this->load->library('rest');

       $config = array(
           'server'          => 'https://api.lob.com/v1/',
           'api_key'         => 'my_api_key',
           'http_auth'       => 'basic',
       );

       $this->rest->initialize($config);
    }

    function show_addresses()
    {
      $result = $this->rest->get('addresses');
    }
}
```

I autoloaded `Curl` since that is required for the library.

Since this is happening with more than one api. I'm sure that it is an issue with my setup but what would it be?

Comment: Apparently no one knows anything on this site because none of my questions ever get answers.

Comment: Can you get a result _without_ Codeigniter?

Comment: If I do: https://api.lob.com/v1/countries?api_key=my_api_key I get a popup that wants a username and password. But the docs say no password is required. Just a api key

Comment: Use your api_key as the username on the website. Change `'api_key' => 'my_api_key'` to ``'http_user' => 'my_api_key'` on your app and see if that helps.

Comment: So on the website that worked. But `http_user` did not work.

Comment: I had to uncomment 'http_auth'       => 'basic', and now it works. Thank you!